# Are finite groups of exponent $d$ rare for $d \neq 4$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

> Is there a way to prove, that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\text{the number of all groups of exponent }d \text{ and order less than }n}{\text{the number of all groups of order less than } n} = 0$ for $d \neq 4$?

This statement is implied by a well known conjecture:

> $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\text{the number of all groups of nilpotency class } 2 \text{, exponent } 4 \text{ and order less than }n}{\text{the number of all groups of order less than } n} = 1$

However, the problem with aforementioned statement is, that it is...

...well, just a conjecture.

Is there a way to strictly prove the main statement of the question?

Comment: From MSE: [More than 99% of groups of order less than 2000 are of order 1024?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241369/more-than-99-of-groups-of-order-less-than-2000-are-of-order-1024)

Comment: Your "well known" conjecture is stronger than any I have come across. The weaker version that almost all finite groups are $2$-groups seems to be widely believed. I have also come across the stronger version that they are almost all of class $2$, but I am not sure how widely believed that is.

Comment: In fact the numerical evidence from groups of order up to $2000$ strongly supports the well known conjecture. About $99.15%$ of groups of order up to $2000$ are $2$-groups. Of the groups of order $2^n$ for $n=8,9,10$ the percentage of groups of class $2$ and exponent $4$ is about $53.6%$, $83.7%$, and $98.6%$, respectively.